# ROS Noetic Python: Subscriber Queueing Delay, Subscriber queue_size not changing

Tags: python, ros, realsense, rospy

I am writing an object detection node in ROS 1 noetic using python to annotate images recorded from a Realsense D455 camera. Object detection is performed by a neural network which takes ~60-70ms to run. When I run the node, the delay as reported by rostopic delay quickly increases to ~700ms, as shown below.

```
# rostopic delay /obj_det/annotations                                                                                                       
subscribed to [/obj_det/annotations]                                                                                                                                                              
average delay: 0.331                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 0.173s max: 0.484s std dev: 0.09673s window: 14                                                                                                                                               
average delay: 0.501                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 0.173s max: 0.685s std dev: 0.16728s window: 31                                                                                                                                               
average delay: 0.562                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 0.173s max: 0.706s std dev: 0.15640s window: 48                                                                                                                                               
average delay: 0.585                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 0.173s max: 0.706s std dev: 0.14014s window: 65                                                                                                                                               
average delay: 0.599                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 0.173s max: 0.706s std dev: 0.12700s window: 83
```

This looks like a classic example of information being published to the input topic faster than it is being consumed by the node, causing delay as the queue becomes filled. Since it takes 60-70ms for the python code to run, if a queue of size 10 is used(ROS default), the queue would quickly fill up, causing each image to wait for 10x the time it takes to execute before being processed by the node. However, I clearly set the subscriber queue size to 1, so no such delay should occur.

```
class ObjectDetectionNode():
    def __init__(self):
        #... other code here
        self.image_output_topic = "/obj_det/annotated"

        self.detector = Detector(options)

        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber(self.image_input_topic, Image, self.callback, queue_size=1)

        self.obj_det_pub = rospy.Publisher(self.track_output_topic, ObjDet3DArray, queue_size=1)
        self.output_image_pub = rospy.Publisher(self.image_output_topic, Image, queue_size=1)
```

I wrote a dummy callback method that simply re-publishes the same image to test queue delay with:

```
    def callback(self, img_msg):
        img = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img_msg, 'bgr8')

        output_img_msg = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(img, encoding='bgr8')
        output_img_msg.header.stamp = img_msg.header.stamp
        self.output_image_pub.publish(output_img_msg)

        time.sleep(1)

        return
```

With a queue size of 1, I would not expect this callback method to accumulate any additional delay despite the fact that it sleeps for 1 whole second. Regardless, ROS seems to accumulate delay as if it had a Subscriber queue size of 10.

```
# rostopic delay /obj_det/annotated                                                                                         [46/363]
subscribed to [/obj_det/annotated ]                                                                                                                                                      
average delay: 1.985                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 1.985s std dev: 0.00000s window: 2                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 2.469                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 2.953s std dev: 0.48428s window: 3                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 2.954                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 3.923s std dev: 0.79124s window: 4                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 3.438                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 4.891s std dev: 1.08329s window: 5                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 3.923                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 5.861s std dev: 1.37044s window: 6                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 4.407                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 6.830s std dev: 1.65510s window: 7                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 4.892                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 7.799s std dev: 1.93824s window: 8                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 5.376                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 8.769s std dev: 2.22065s window: 9                                                                                                                                                
average delay: 5.787                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 9.072s std dev: 2.39428s window: 10                                                                                                                                               
average delay: 6.213                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 10.042s std dev: 2.60547s window: 11                                                                                                                                              
average delay: 6.564                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 10.079s std dev: 2.72151s window: 12                                                                                                                                              
average delay: 6.857                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 10.082s std dev: 2.78118s window: 13                                                                                                                                              
average delay: 7.028                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 10.082s std dev: 2.73693s window: 14                                                                                                                                              
average delay: 7.244                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 10.082s std dev: 2.74971s window: 15                                                                                                                                              
average delay: 7.433                                                                                                                                                                                       
        min: 1.985s max: 10.082s std dev: 2.74871s window: 16
```

It looks like establishing the publisher-subscriber connection with a queue size of one with the line `self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber(self.image_input_topic, Image, self.callback, queue_size=1)` simply does not actually work. I even tried changing the specified queue size to 20 to see if that increased the maximum delay reported by rostopic up to 20s, but the output is the same as seen above(ie, the value of queue_size passed to rospy.Subscriber doesn't seem to do anything). Have I messed up somewhere along the way here?

Answer (score 0):

In python each callback gets a thread so actually you are running more than one callback and that is creating the delay.
try putting in a latch, something like

```
def callback(self, img_msg):
  if(self.is_running):
    return
  self.is_running = True
  img = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img_msg, 'bgr8')

  output_img_msg = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(img, encoding='bgr8')
  output_img_msg.header.stamp = img_msg.header.stamp
  self.output_image_pub.publish(output_img_msg)

  time.sleep(1)
  self.is_running = False
  return
```